# _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".36689776"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Пишу игру шахматы на Python3, использую Tkinter. Режим игры с ботом. То есть когда ходит на человек, он нажимает на кнопки, означающие клетки поля, и таким образом ходит. После хода человека должен ходить бот

```
while king_alive:
    global bot_turn
    if bot_turn:
        cells = l.bot_move(log_field)
        print(cells[0].x, cells[0].y, cells[1].x, cells[1].y)
        replace(cells[0], cells[1])
        bot_turn = False
```

а вот функция replace, которая меняет состояние клеток шахматного поля

```
def replace(first_cell, second_cell):
    if second_cell.figure.type != 'nofig':
        delete_fig(second_cell.figure)
    first_cell.clicked = False
    second_cell.clicked = False
    second_cell.fig_name = first_cell.fig_name
    second_cell.fig_owner = first_cell.fig_owner
    second_cell.figure = second_cell.get_figure()
    first_cell.figure = l.NoFigure(first_cell.x, first_cell.y, "")
    first_cell.fig_name = ""
    first_cell.fig_owner = ""
    field[second_cell.x][second_cell.y].configure(fg=second_cell.fig_owner, text=second_cell.fig_name)
    field[first_cell.x][first_cell.y].configure(text="")
 demark_cells()
```

человек нормально ходит, все нормально перерисовывается, а вот бот ничего не двигает (входные данные для метода replace точно корректны). Выводит вот такие ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Даша/Desktop/python/task chess/graphics.py", line 176, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Даша/Desktop/python/task chess/graphics.py", line 171, in main
    replace(cells[0], cells[1])
  File "C:/Users/Даша/Desktop/python/task chess/graphics.py", line 138, in replace
    field[second_cell.x][second_cell.y]['fg'] = second_cell.fig_owner
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1275, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1268, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1259, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
  _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".36689776"
```

в чем проблема?

Comment: А что здесь написано (176 строке)? `"C:/Users/Даша/Desktop/python/task chess/graphics.py", line 176`

Comment: как команда ".36689776" формируется?

Comment: вот и я хотела бы знать, что эта команда обозначает

Answer (score 1):

1. При возникновении подобных "странностей" со стороны tkinter попробуйте запустить код на версии 3.6 Python'а. Там tkinter проливает свет на непонятный `command`, которым оказывается имя Tk-объекта, в методе которого произошло исключение.
2. В Python 3.4 (и возможно других версиях) непонятные числа в ошибке tkinter (в Вашем случае `36689776`) - это **id объекта**, в методе которого произошел exception.
3. Предполагаю (т.к. проверить полный код не представляется возможным), что exception кинула кнопка (это ведь `Button`?) `field[second_cell.x][second_cell.y]` при вызове метода `configure()`.
4. Исключение происходит, когда метод configure пытается **установить цвет шрифта** (опция `fg=`) в значение `second_cell.fig_owner` (где хранится либо неправильное имя цвета, либо там вообще не цвет).